# find all values form join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When i run this on console:

```
ItemCategory.joins(:item_companies)
```

I got the my sql query is:

```
SELECT `item_categories`.* FROM `item_categories` INNER JOIN `item_companies` ON `item_companies`.`item_category_id` = `item_categories`.`id`
```

But i want all columns after joins that is all the columns of items companies and items categories. Please help me.

Comment: try ItemCategory.select("*").joins(:item_companies)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
item_categories = ItemCategory.includes(:item_companies)
```

Which loas the item cateogires and then the item companies as well in one shoot, then later you can do:

```
item_categories.each { |ic| ic.item_companies }
```

And you will realized that no sql is performed, because they were all loaded when you ran the query with **includes**

Answer (score 0):

As Carlos suggested in the comments you need to add a .select in order to specify the additional fields from the joined table. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.

Adding the following sometimes works:

```
ItemCategory.select("item_categories.*, item_companies.*").joins(:item_companies)
```

Although you can try just * I have found issues with the extra id field breaking objects later. You can extend the select to do something like this to remove the duplicate standard fields:

```
fnew = (item_companies.column_names - ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])
fnew.map! {|f| "item_companies.#{f}"}
fnew_text = fnew.join(', ')
.select("item_categories.*, #{fnew_text}")
```

Obviously there are probably easier ways to do this, and you could add a method to make this easier. In order to avoid getting strange lookups on the joined ID this was the brute force approach I used.